# Как показывать на странице по 3 объекта из массива?

Tags: javascript

Суть вопроса такая. Как показывать по 3 объявления на странице из массива. Ну то есть если пользователь находится на первой странице, то первые три элемента массива, если на второй то следующие 3 элемента массива, если на третей то след три и так далее.... Короче переключалку, как на сайте с объявлениями. Как правильно фильтровать

```js
let intervaltwo = ["asdasd", "asdasd", "asdasd", "asdasd", "asdasd", "asdasd", "asdasd", "asdasd", "asdasd"];
pagefrom = 0;
pagefrom = 3;


intervaltree = intervaltwo.filter(function(item, i, arr) {
  return i >= pagefrom && i <= pagebefore;
});

console.log(intervaltree);
```

Comment: Может [`.slice(page * pagesize, (page + 1) * pagesize)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать .slice()

```
let intervaltwo = ["asdasd1", "asdasd2", "asdasd3", "asdasd4", "asdasd5", "asdasd6", "asdasd7", "asdasd8", "asdasd9"];
/* Индексация с нуля */
/*
 * 0 - первая страница
 * 1 - вторая
 * и т.д.
 */
var page = 3 - 1;
if (page < 0)
    return;
var start = page * 3;
var count = (page > 0) ? start : 3;

console.log(intervaltwo.slice(start, start + count));
```